# Java AWT Robot - how to read item text / label?

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

I need to select appropriate option from the popup window. Unfortunately, it is not the popup displayed by the web page, so I cannot use Selenium framework for that purpose.

As I checked, it is possible to navigate to different option by pressing arrow keys. Thus `keyPress` and `keyRelease`​ from Java AWT [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html) should work for me perfectly to select option and confirm the selection by pressing Enter key.

Unfortunately, I do not see a method to read currently selected item text. Without that I cannot find appropriate option. Is it possible to read item label using Java AWT Robot?

Answer (score 0):

If the target application is another java application, then you should be able to get a reference to the component hierarchy and traverse it until you find the text field & label in question.

Assuming it's not a java application, then I don't believe it's possible to do this - at least directly. `Robot` just provides mouse / keyboard input, but you could use it combined with other classes in the toolkit to at least partially solve your problem.

Use the `Robot` methods `keyPress` & `keyRelease` to input <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>.  Then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

Once the text is in the clipboard, you could read it using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)`

You *might* be able to use the same approach for a text label, assuming it is selectable.

This question is talking about using java.awt.Robot to alter text in another program (MS excel), but it might provide you some additional ideas for tackling the problem:

[How can I select text in another application with java.awt.robot (example: shift+home)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023187/how-can-i-select-text-in-another-application-with-java-awt-robot-example-shift)